# Обеспечить правильную ширину inline-block'у с колонками

Tags: html, css, css3

Хочу сделать `inline-block` с горизонтальными колонками. Т. е. надо, чтобы каждый inline-block был по ширине равен минимальному количеству колонок, в которые помещается его содержимое.

Проблема в том, что браузеры как-то странно обрабатывают колонки.

```css
div {
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;

  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan. Pro sale deseruisse ad. Vix cu integre fuisset insolens. Quo perfecto pericula ex. Te nam tritani honestatis, eam integre virtute ut.</p>
  <p>Cum an autem affert laoreet, ea ius falli impedit ocurreret. No duo aperiam perfecto lobortis, ut mea aliquid graecis, te has facete sententiae. Ut singulis laboramus his, meis laoreet docendi ius ad. Duo nisl alterum perfecto no, eum in etiam laboramus prodesset, rebum nobis nusquam in sit. Usu at expetendis consectetuer.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan. Pro sale deseruisse ad. Vix cu integre fuisset insolens. Quo perfecto pericula ex. Te nam tritani honestatis, eam integre virtute ut.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

**Chrome**, похоже, определяет ширину блока без учёта колонок, а затем в получившемся размещает колонки. У первого блока явно есть пустое пространство на лишнюю колонку. Остальным блокам вполне хватило бы одной колонки, но они получили разную ширину.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

**Firefox** всем блокам ставит ширину в одну колонку, а текст накладывается. При желании переполнение можно запихнуть под полосу прокрутки, но сделать так, чтобы блок получил нужную ширину не удаётся.

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Также имеется костыль, заставляющий Chrome вести себя как firefox:

```css
div {
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;

  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  
  /* chrome to firefox */
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
  min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan. Pro sale deseruisse ad. Vix cu integre fuisset insolens. Quo perfecto pericula ex. Te nam tritani honestatis, eam integre virtute ut.</p>
  <p>Cum an autem affert laoreet, ea ius falli impedit ocurreret. No duo aperiam perfecto lobortis, ut mea aliquid graecis, te has facete sententiae. Ut singulis laboramus his, meis laoreet docendi ius ad. Duo nisl alterum perfecto no, eum in etiam laboramus prodesset, rebum nobis nusquam in sit. Usu at expetendis consectetuer.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan. Pro sale deseruisse ad. Vix cu integre fuisset insolens. Quo perfecto pericula ex. Te nam tritani honestatis, eam integre virtute ut.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Должно получиться что-то такое:

[image: Expected result]

PS: [Этот вопрос по-английски.](//stackoverflow.com/q/38598799/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38598799/4928642

Answer (score 1):

column-width: 10em; - em зависит от  родительского контейнера и не реагирует на ширину браузера, соответственно если контейнеру не хватает даже .1 em он будет в другой строке. и справа будет пустое место.
лучше использовать %-соотношение или vw. 
Попробуйте использовать flex-basis и justify-content: space-between;

соответственно структуре вопроса: width: auto; max-width: 100%; - в данном случае ширина блока зависит от его наполнения и не превышает 100%. - это установка для родителя

Comment: 1. А можно пояснить, как это вообще связано с вопросом? 2. В плане переноса все единицы измерения (кроме самого px) могут приводить к дробным пикселям. И это, вроде, тоже не относится к вопросу. 3. Каким образом предлагается использовать flex, если  dom-элемент != колонка?

Comment: 1. у вас колонки располагаются в блоке согласно ширине в 10em, em - это пропорциональная величина, зависящая от ширины и высоты родителя, но размещаются колонки в ширину, если учитывать что между колонками существует отступы, то сначала html формирует отступы, а потом формирует тело, и если тело не вмещается даже в .1 em - он его перенесет. % или vw формируется пропорциональностью по отношению к родителю или к окну браузера, что позволяет разместить колонки в пределах 100% родителя. В html дробных пикселей нету, он округляет их до целых в большую сторону.

Comment: если использовать не inline-block, а inline-flex, то можно элементу задать базовую ширину через flex-basis. justify-content: space-between; - расположит участки на всю ширину контейнера, распределив неиспользованное место между другими контейнерами, соответственно такого среза справа не будет, будет выровнена структура. DOM-элементы вы устанавливаете для вставки, но для семантики используется язык html, который позволит настроить структуру вывода DOM в необходимом виде

Comment: если вам надо добиться чтобы блок уменьшался то смотрите исправленный ответ выше

Comment: Юрий, пожалуйста, не поднимайте вопросы с глубины сайта. На этот вопрос был уже дан ответ в английской версии сайта сразу после того, как его задали

Comment: 1. [Не в большую.](//stackoverflow.com/q/40517229/4928642) 2. Про единицы измерения что-то вообще не похоже на правду. 3. Советую перечитать вопрос, потому что я вообще не понимаю, какую проблемы ты пытаешься решить. Какая максимальная ширина? Я не просил такого. Какие блоки? При чём тут флекс?

Comment: @Yuri, не правда. Там нет нормального ответа. К тому же, с чего это не надо поднимать вопросы? Ещё как надо, за это даже знаки есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, используйте `display:flex`. Единственное, что могу посоветовать

Comment: @Yuri, а в виде работающего сниппета в ответе можно?

Comment: @Qwertiy, сейчас попробую наколдовать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49977/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-yuri).

Answer (score 0):

Только со скриптом. По-другому никак: https://jsfiddle.net/f64bjs61/1/

```js
$(function() {
 $('div').each(function() {
   var num = $(this).find('p').length,
      w = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
     if($(this).find('p').eq(i).outerHeight() > $(this).outerHeight()){
       var n = $(this).find('p').eq(i).outerHeight() / $(this).outerHeight();
        if(Math.round(n) < n){n = Math.round(n) + 1}else{n = Math.round(n)};
        w = w + (n * $(this).find('p').eq(i).outerWidth());
      }else{
       w = w + $(this).find('p').eq(i).outerWidth();
      };
    };
    $(this).css({width: w});
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;

  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan. Pro sale deseruisse ad. Vix cu integre fuisset insolens. Quo perfecto pericula ex. Te nam tritani honestatis, eam integre virtute ut.</p>
  <p>Cum an autem affert laoreet, ea ius falli impedit ocurreret. No duo aperiam perfecto lobortis, ut mea aliquid graecis, te has facete sententiae. Ut singulis laboramus his, meis laoreet docendi ius ad. Duo nisl alterum perfecto no, eum in etiam laboramus prodesset, rebum nobis nusquam in sit. Usu at expetendis consectetuer.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan. Pro sale deseruisse ad. Vix cu integre fuisset insolens. Quo perfecto pericula ex. Te nam tritani honestatis, eam integre virtute ut.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an nec posse homero accumsan.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```