# Почему уменя вместо overflow-x делается overflow-x overflow-y?

Tags: html, css

Уменя почемуто блок со статусом скролится не по горизонтали (overflow-x:scroll;) а по вертикали (overflow-y:scroll;)

```css
.status{
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.status p{
  height:25px;
}
.scroll-x {
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
<input id="edit-stat" value="Изменить статус" type="submit">
    <div class="scroll-x">тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы бы что ли вместо скринов код добавили, в ответе есть пункт меню "фрагмент кода"

Comment: .scroll-x { overflow-x:scroll; }

Comment: Так не заработает...

Comment: @DenisPupyrev, это опечатка, она почти не влияет на результат.

Comment: Кстати, похожие вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/548849/178988 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549065/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заставить текст подгоняться под высоту вместо ширины, скорее всего, не получится.

Возможно, тебе подойдут колонки:

```css
.status {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#edit-stat {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.scroll-x {
  -moz-column-width: 400px;
  column-width: 400px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;

  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <input id="edit-stat" value="Изменить статус" type="submit">
  <div class="scroll-x">
    тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

или так, если попроще. У родителя добавить overflow-x:scroll; , а у дочернего очень большую ширину.

ну или можно сделать текст в 1 строчку, white-space: nowrap; - тогда даже без определения ширины дочернего элемента будет скрол

```css
.status{
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
.status p{
  height:25px;
}
.scroll-x {
  
  width:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
<input id="edit-stat" value="Изменить статус" type="submit">
    <div class="scroll-x">тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. тут длинный текст, но он почему-то скролится не по горизонтали а по вертикали. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: ну раз помогло - отметьте решением

Comment: Как отметить ??

Comment: галочку слева отметить, но вы уже приняли другой ответ, вряд ли получится